# Most idiomatic way in NUnit to assert equal length on collections

Tags: .net, unit-testing, collections, nunit, assert

What's the most idiomatic way with NUnit 2.6 to assert that two collections are of equal length regardless of their elements' values?

I can see several ways of expressing that assertion. Which one is preferred, or are there disadvantages/advantages with using one or the other?

```
Assert.That(coll1, Has.Count.EqualTo(coll2.Count));
Assert.That(coll1.Count, Is.EqualTo(coll2.Count));
Assert.AreEqual(coll1.Count, coll2.Count);
```

I can see that the first option provides a nice output in case the assertion failed (Expected count of ... but actually got ...), whereas the other two options only output "Expected ..., actual ..." unless I provide a custom message through an additional parameter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I prefer:

```
Assert.That(collection, Has.Count.EqualTo(expectedCount));
```

Simply because `.Count` and `Count()` could be incorrectly overridden (which should be tested in a different unit test if they are, although I don't know how nunit is actually doing the count internally).  Bascially I don't want my actual to have any side affect logic.  Calling `Count` or `Count()` should probably be done in the act like:

```
// Arrange
var expectedCount = 8;

// Act
var list = GetList();
var actualCount = list.Count();

// Assert
Assert.That(actualCount, Is.EqualTo(expectedCount));
```

Both read fairly the same, but the first one has less *logic* to look over when it fails.

Update: dec-1-2020

Considering the number of upvotes this has received, I think I should mention that using https://fluentassertions.com/ (FA) is advantageous.  This could be written in the following ways and reads much nicer:

```
// Arrange

// Act
var list = GetList();

// Assert
list.Should().BeEmpty();
```

or

```
// Arrange

// Act
var list = GetList();

// Assert
list.Should().HaveCount(8);
```

or

```
// Arrange

// Act
var list = GetList();

// Assert
list.Should().HaveCountLessThanOrEqualTo(10);
```

Beyond the OP question, FA can do some very advanced collection rules:

```
// Arrange

// Act
var persons = GetPersons();

// Assert
persons.Should().BeInAscendingOrder(p => p.LastName)
  .And().OnlyHaveUniqueItems(p => p.id);
```

The framework goes way beyond collections and adds readability to testing other topics as well.

```
// Arrange

// Act
Action action = () => 8 / 0;

//
action.Should().Throw<DivideByZeroException>();
```

I have no association with fluent assertions.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's personal preference really but for I go for:

```
Assert.That(coll1.Count(), Is.EqualTo(coll2.Count()));
```

Using linq and if the underlying collection/Enumerable type changed it would still work in most cases, you not testing the type just the count.  This also works for things that don't have `.Count` on them like `IDBSet` for example.  But then again I don't see anything wrong with `.AreEqual` either. If the next engineer understands then  it's a winner, eh?